# Wysiwyg Insert Image shows blank page in production mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, 404, wysiwyg, magento2.2.0

After putting my webshop in production mode and try to insert an image in the Wysiwyg editor it gives me a blank popup modal apart from text saying insert image and a close button.
In developer mode everything works fine.

The console gives me a 404 error.
[image: 404 Error]

The other Wysiwyg functions all work fine even the video upload function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the pub folder as the root of the webserver as Magento suggests doing.

After setting the pub folder as root all I had to do is regenerate the static content and the image selecter worked fine.